# Webpack failing to use babel-loader despite its presence in webpack.config.js

Tags: webpack, babeljs

I have a weird issue where babel-loader is being completely ignored even though it is correctly referenced in my webpack.config.js file.

The error is:

```
Hash: d9f2eead3307d16f76f3
Version: webpack 1.12.0
Time: 37ms
    + 1 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module parse failed: D:\Dropbox\Work\node_modules\cycle-apptools\src\index.js Line 3: Unexpected token
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| var x = `hello${1}`;
|
| import foo from './foo';
|
| function run() {
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: './dist',
    filename: 'index.js',
    sourceMapFilename: 'index.js.map'
  },
  devtool: '#source-map'
};
```

I have the following npm packages installed:

```
"babel-core": "^5.8.23",
"babel-loader": "^5.3.2",
"gulp": "^3.9.0",
"gulp-babel": "^5.2.1",
"gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
"webpack": "^1.12.0"
```

my index.js file looks like this:

```
var x = `hello${1}`;

import foo from './foo';

function run() {
  console.log('foo:', foo.foo);
  throw new Error('AppTools run is not yet implemented');
}

export default {
  run
}
```

... and foo.js looks like this:

```
export default {
  foo: 1
};
```

finally, here's my directory structure, courtesy of sublime text:

[image]

Why is webpack ignoring babel loader?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. I'm developing inside a node_modules folder in my dev root so that I can test my custom modules in my local projects without having to redeploy to npm every time I make a change. The exclusion pattern is filtering out my source files because of that.

Comment: could you please explain more what I have to do? I got the same situation

thanks

Comment: @hoangk look in webpack.config.js for the line `exclude: /node_modules/` - all of the files in your project are inside node_modules, so they're being filtered out, because the exclusion exists on the premise that you don't want to include stuff in your node_modules folder. You have to update that line to be more specific; prefix it with your project folder name or something.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you so much for following up with this answer, I literally spent hours trying to find out why can't I build a project installed as dependency inside `node_modules`!